# Sharepoint ribbon and navbar font color not working when applying theme in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, spfx, modern-experience

With the following script i set a theme in a sitecollection

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://mySP.sharepoint.com/sites/test2 -Credentials $script:psCredentials
Set-PnPTheme -FontSchemeUrl _catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme004.spfont -ColorPaletteUrl _catalogs/theme/15/palette025.spcolor
```

If i understand this correct palette025.spcolor is the "Dark Yellow" theme. 
When the theme is set with powershell this is the result:
 [image]

As you can see the theme is now darkyellow but the font color is wrong. If i add SPFx extension TopNavBar that also has wrong font color. 
 
When i am adding theme manually from sharepoint it gives the same result, It looks fine in the menu but when i press Apply its getting wrong again.
[image]

What i can see from debugging the page its this css that messing this up.

```
<span class="ms-CommandBarItem-commandText itemCommandText_cf1861fb">Page details​</span>

   .SPPageChrome-app .ms-CommandBar .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
color: #333333;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 0 4px;
}
```

While i am in the menu of selecting a theme "When the theme is working" before i Apply this is the css

```
<span class="ms-CommandBarItem-commandText itemCommandText_cf1861fb">Page details​</span>

.SPPageChrome-app .ms-CommandBar .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
color: #ffffff;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 0 4px;
}
```

If i navigate to Documents or sitecontents the font color is correct.

My thoughts about the problem is:

- When a new sitecollection is created a theme catalog is created with this path: _catalogs/theme/15/ and copying all available themes here from the root gallery . The root palette025.spcolor have a font color property that is wrong.
- This is a office ui fabric css and its some kind of css failure

Does anyone know how to edit the font color or reset it so i can get the menu text back?

Comment: I might add that all dark theme the font color is wrong.